# #each with call to helper ignores first entry in array

Tags: coffeescript, meteor, handlebars.js

I'm trying to generate a menu with handlebars, based on this array (from coffeescript):

```
Template.moduleHeader.modules = -> [
    { "moduleName": "dashboard", "linkName": "Dashboard" }
    { "moduleName": "roomManager", "linkName": "Raumverwaltung" }
    { "moduleName": "userManager", "linkName": "Benutzerverwaltung" }
]
```

The iteration looks like this (from the html code):

```
{{#each modules}}
<li {{this.isActive this.moduleName}}>
    <a class="{{this.moduleName}}" href="#">{{this.linkName}}</a>
</li>
{{/each}}
```

`{{this.isActive}}` is defined like this (coffeescript code again):

```
Template.moduleHeader.isActive = (currentModuleName) ->
    if currentModuleName is Session.get 'module'
        "class=active"
```

Based on `Session.get 'module'` the appropriate menu item is highlighted with the css class *active*.

On reload, the Session-variable `module` contains 'dashboard', which is the first entry in that array, however, it does not get the *active*-class. If I add an empty object as the first item to the `modules`-array, the 'dashboard'-item is properly highlighted.

The strange thing is, that the first item (dashboard) is rendered fine, but it does not have the *active*-class, which raises the impression, that the function `this.isActive` is not called for the first item.

Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: have you tried wrapping the `{{#each modules}} {{/each}}` in `{{#if modules}} {{/if}}`?

Comment: Yes (upon your question), but it does not change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really going out on a whim here but my traditional approach would be below. I don't know whether it will work but it was too big for a comment, yet again it's not a guaranteed fix. Let me know how it goes:

Replace the HTML with

```
{{#each modules}}
<li {{isActive}}>
    <a class="{{moduleName}}" href="#">{{linkName}}</a>
</li>
{{/each}}
```

Replace the CS with

```
Template.moduleHeader.isActive = () ->
    currentModule = this
    currentModuleName = currentModule.moduleName
    if currentModuleName is Session.get 'module'
        "class=active"
```

Comment: Yes, that works fine. Thanks! I guess I still have to get used to the 'this'-context in the handbars-helpers.

Comment: @Brauer awesome, wasn't expecting it to. I don't really understand why your syntax didnt work as AFAIK the lack of `this` just assumes it is `this`... oh well, glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

If its rendering, the each block is working correctly. There must be an issue in the isActive helper. Most likely the if block isn't working as you think it should be. Put a console.log in there and see if it is entered, and put another inside the if (printf debugging). I find this is usually the easiest way to do quick debugging of handlebars helpers.

A useful helper in js for inspecting values inside of a context is as follows

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("debug", function(optionalValue) { 
    console.log("Current Context"); 
    console.log("===================="); 
    console.log(this); 
    if (optionalValue) { 
        console.log("Value"); 
        console.log("===================="); 
        console.log(optionalValue); 
    } 
});
```

Then you can call this inside an each block and see all the values the current context/a specific value has.